# cannot insert the username in to the field even though it is getting the id in selenium python

Tags: python, testing, selenium, browser-automation

I am new to selenium. I want to test my site. I want to test with more than 100 clients. I have written this code. The strange part is that the password field is filling up but the username field is not filling up. The value is_displayed() is returning true but the data is not inserting into the field. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
import time
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://isec.uta.edu:8060' )
print browser.current_url
for i in range(0,10):
    time.sleep(1)

username = browser.find_element_by_id("username" )
password = browser.find_element_by_id("password" )
submit   = browser.find_element_by_id("usernameButton")
a = username.is_displayed()
print a #prints true as it can find the id =username
username.send_keys("please god")
password.send_keys("display" )
submit.click()
```

Here is the HTML for it

```
<form id="username_form">
<div id="username_taken" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Sorry, that username is taken.</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="uname" class="control-label">Username:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your username."
    id="username">
    <br>
    <label for="password" class="control-label">Password:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" class="form-control" data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="top" title="Please enter your password to unlock the contacts"
    placeholder="Enter your password (optional)" id="password">
    <br>
    <div class="togglebutton">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="private"> Allow my friends to find me. </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button id="usernameButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you  see the username filed being populated? Can you post some of the HTML?

Comment: Are you sure that the document only contains one element with id="username"?

Comment: Yes. please visit isec.uta.edu:8060 to confirm.I have tried it but i am not able to fill the username

Comment: I am closing the form tag. if I had not closed the form then the password value won't be filled in it.

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned URL (http://isec.uta.edu:8060/) is displaying as "The connection was reset"